# How to traverse through XML file and fetch a particular value and pass it on to for each controller

Tags: jmeter

From my previous response I am getting the following XML,

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    -
    <viewList>
    -
        <view title="107cd5b450594e9ba1e2834b10ccfcb" transaction_id="307288fbcc9948f8ab6596d2a3b336a7" key_testcase="52dc4c0bcdb6413484cab16f43ef9d49" active="true" raw="true">
            <testcase id="52dc4c0bcdb6413484cab16f43ef9d49" size="530374"/>
            <testcase id="5d7e204dec034bfaa130757a98728816" size="530374"/>
            <testcase id="e165b07bea874896be6d2aa81abeac19" size="530374"/>
            <testcase id="3ac054f9bbec41f8b39f4fe236e4e358" size="530374"/>
            <testcase id="e4c48aee4aa4b588e1c263290722212" size="530374"/>
            <testcase id="389cf80bdcb4e27b7fd2cd07fd7464a" size="530374"/>
            <testcase id="17cd8be81227463e8ccbfd6b4263b872" size="530374"/>
            <testcase id="2d8b3214ae441948edfc472cb654cb" size="530374"/>
            <testcase id="610004abc53b45dbb7d075c7c02b1fae" size="530374"/>
            <testcase id="121a016bc32e43779a634b7990687312" size="530374"/>
            <testcase id="119b1fd4e4334b1a84707e2fd67667b4" size="530374"/>
            <testcase id="9253b4da50ff488081e9fd3e93da85c" size="530374"/>
            <testcase id="808c3055549c48e2a0e3a95aadd54918" size="530374"/>
    </view>
</viewList>
```

Want to retrieve all test case it and pass it to for each controller. How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

1. Add it as a child of the request which returns the above XML and configure as follows:

   [image]
2. Then add [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) and set it up like:

   [image]
3. That's it, the XPath Extractor will fetch all testcases ids and ForEach Controller will iterate all of them, you will be able to refer the current testcase id inside the ForEach Controller as `${testcase_id}` where required:

   [image]

More information: [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xpath-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: 2023-06-29 16:30:04,215 WARN o.a.j.e.XPathExtractor: SAXException while processing (//testcase /@id). Content is not allowed in prolog.

I am getting this error

Comment: Well, it means that you're getting not valid XML, try checking `Use Tidy` box, it may help, otherwise you will need to go for [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor)

Comment: Yeah there are two `-` which I cannot remove as it is present in the response

Comment: Then Tidy won't help, you will need to switch to another PostProcessor, for example this regular expression `testcase id="(\w+)"` should extract the IDs for you as well.